# Python use pythonnet module can't import the C# DLL Library

Tags: python, c#

This is the C# Library Code:(Save to **PyLibray.dll**)

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PyLibray
{
    class Voice
    {
        public void Beep(int freq, int duration)
        {
            Console.Beep(freq, duration);
        }
        public void NormalBeep()
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        //https://www.cnblogs.com/Microblue/archive/2010/09/21/2406704.html
        public void Asterisk()
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
        }
        public void Exclamation()
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
        }
        public void Hand()
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
        }
        public void Question()
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Question.Play();
        }
        public void playWaveAudio(string path, bool is_looping = false)
        {

            System.Media.SoundPlayer sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            sp.SoundLocation = @path;
            if (is_looping)
            {
                sp.PlayLooping();
            }
            else
            {
                sp.Play();
            }

        }



}
```

This code write a namespace **PyLibray** and defined some futc like play voice and beep
People say it should be written like this, but there's something terribly wrong with my machine!

This is Python Code:

```py
import clr

clr.AddReference('PyLibray')

import PyLibray
instance=PyLibray.Voice();
instance.NormalBeep();
```

But it's wrong!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PyLibray
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyLibray'
```

Comment: Not familiar with pythonnet, but could it be that PyLibrary.dll is not in the lib lookup path?

Comment: @chamilad is OK, sir.

Comment: @chamilad I will take it.